# call applet in spring class

Tags: spring, jsp, applet

how to call a applet in spring control class?

Answer (score 1):

Spring is mostly used on server-side, and applets - on client side. So I'd assume two scenarios:

- you want to use spring in your applet - then simply ship the spring jars, the `applicationContext.xml` and start with instantiating [`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html) for example.
- you want to reuse functionality from an applet on the server side - in that case move that functionality to a helper class, and import it in both the applet and the spring beans.